# how many MYSQL connections allow to set per 1G RAM

Tags: mysql, connection

I always see `too many connections 1040` in the web. so we can change the max_connections. but how many MYSQL connections allow to set per 1G memory? in linux and windows surrounding. this memory is extral

Comment: That seems like a fairly large number of connections. I'd hazard a guess that you're not managing connections correctly - say, by pooling them.

Comment: A connection in MySQL has fairly minimal overhead in terms of resources. The question is whether you'd want to take the chance that that many concurrent users all do something on the database at the same time.

Comment: @Matt Ball, @Marc B,  I want rent a Dedicated Server witch has 2G RAM. In Linux and windows operation system, how many MYSQL connections can I set maximize? Thanks.